# How to load VBO and render it on separate Java threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, opengl, lwjgl, vao

To create a virtual world I am using Lightweight Java Game Library (LWJGL) (Java + OpenGL). I want to load my terrains into graphics card memory on worker thread, while on main thread I want to take these, already loaded terrains, and render them. In order to do that I have to create Vertex Array Object (VAO), create Vertex Buffer Object (VBO), add VBO into VAO attribute list and finally render everything. This works perfectly on single-threaded system, however I am having problems implementing it on multi-threaded system. I know that VBO can be shared between OpenGL contexts, while VAO cannot be shared ([reference1](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification); [reference2](https://blog.gvnott.com/some-usefull-facts-about-multipul-opengl-contexts/)). Therefore to accomplish my goal I:

1. create VAO on main thread,
2. create VBO on worker tread by using these methods:

   GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ID);
   int ID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
   GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
   GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(attributeNr, coordSize, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
   GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
3. render it on main thread, however I get this
   exception:

*Exception in thread "main" org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Cannot use offsets when Element Array Buffer Object is disabled*

I am sure that I do not render not loaded terrains, because I load terrains when they are outside render scope. I have read many articles, questions and blogs about OpenGL shared contexts and concurrency, but did not managed to find a solution. I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: We need more code, especially 1 and 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already stated, VAOs are *NOT* shared between contexts, so it is also impossible to modify them from multiple threads.

```
GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(attributeNr, coordSize, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

is modifying the VAO state, thus it has to be called from the main thread.

It is perfectly fine to have the data upload (`glBufferData`) in a separate thread, but constructing the VAO can only be done from the main thread.

Comment: It seems that you are right. However I had to reconstruct all my code and I am getting few other errors (hopefully non-related). I will accept your answer as soon as I am done dealing with these errors. Thank you.